# Is it ok to return integer from template function?

Tags: c++, templates, function

I want to write a sign function template. I did it like this:

```
template<class T> T sign(const T &value)
{
    if (value > 0) return 1;
    else if (value < 0) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

It's working, but i'm not sure if it is good to return a numerical value when actually my function should return T. Is this function good ?

Comment: You are relying on implicit conversion - which can be dangerous, unless for all types of `T` you understand the exact behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it might be dangerous, but this seems to be exactly the intended behavior - sign being the -1/0/1 of the same type.

Comment: You probably should return an `int`, because it could be more efficient than your T (imagine if T is a multi-prevision bignum). Or you could use an `enum { Negative=-1, Zero=0, Positive=+1 }` or even (if C++11) an enum class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `T` might be a type that doesn't have a cast from integer.

In that case it will fail at compile time.

If you want it to be an integer by design, declare it so.

```
template<class T> int sign(const T &value)
{
    if (value > 0) return 1;
    else if (value < 0) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function will only compile if there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `T`. If that's your intention it is okay, but it doesn't really look good.

I think it's better if you rewrite your code to return a `T`, maybe using something like:

```
//return T(0);
return static_cast<T>(0); // Better alternative as suggested by Steve Jessop
```

This explicitly constructs a `T` from the int. Be aware though that if someone calls this method with a `T` that can construct from an `int` it will work - regardless of what that constructor really means.

Comment: Regarding "be aware", `static_cast<T>(0)` might be a little safer. It rules out `void*`, which your suggested C-style cast doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you use T as return type? You should consider changing it to some integral or `enum{USINGNED,ZERO,SIGNED}`. In that case, your function will work as long as T has overloaded operators `>` and `<`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can cast -1/0/1 to `T`, this is exactly what will happen. I believe what you want to achieve is having sign of the same type as input, so the only thing you can do is add explicit cast which will make almost no difference — as Steve noted in comments, it will make a difference depending on the T explicit constructor.

Comment: Whether there's a cast or not would make a difference if `T` had an `explicit` constructor taking `int`.

Comment: Well, true. Now the question is whether it's good or bad, I'd add your remark to my answer and will let OP decide.

Comment: Agreed, the questioner has to decide. Does he want the template to fail for types to which `int` can be converted explicitly but not implicitly? As an example, `vector` has an explicit conversion to `int`, since it has an explicit constructor that takes `size_type`, and that would probably fail if passed `-1`. This template won't instantiate for `vector` anyway, since vector has no `<`, `>` comparison to `int`, but it's a warning of the sort of thing that you should expect a cast to do. As another example, `int` can be cast to `void*`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fine because T will be number as you want to find out sign.
Lets see the caller function.

```
double x = -5.2;
int ret = sign(x);
```

in last statement, sign will return int constant which will be assigned to ret (implicit type cast if required);